# svcutils and class COM visible

Tags: class, dll, com

I have a WSDL service that exposes one class.
Using svcutils I get class that I need.
The problem is that this class must be visible from a VB6 client that references DLL .NET that references WSDL.
From VB6 I can see the class but not its properties so I don't have intellisense enabled.
How can I tell svcutil to export GUID (or more) to let class visible COM?
thank you

Comment: You are not supposed to see it at all.  But you probably used the sledgehammer approach and ticked the "Make assembly COM-visible" checkbox.  Which exposes every single public class in the project visible, it relies on the default value of [ClassInterface].  Intentionally de-tuned to ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch because doing this is so extremely dangerous.  You must use late-binding in the client code to avoid the major hazards of DLL Hell, one consequence is that auto-complete no longer works in the VBA editor.  Just don't do this, wrap the WSDL object with your own wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

COM and WSDL(WebService) are separate technologies, there is no direct cooperation between them.

You need to create a program to relay between them yourself.

If you can convert WSDL to WCF contract, you can call it from VB6 by creating a program that calls WebService with C# and putting it in a format that can be called by COM.

In that case, you need to assemble GUID, IDL etc yourself.
For an overview and method, please refer to the following articles.
[Interoperability (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/)
[Exposing .NET Framework Components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/exposing-dotnet-components-to-com)

However, please note that it is not always possible to convert WSDL to WCF contract. In that case you need to create a program that accesses WebService from scratch or using another technology.